# Sourcemaps on minified js built in Dart release mode not working

Tags: dart, source-maps, minifiedjs

Dart application built in release mode with Sourcemaps turned on in pubspec.yaml do not work in Chrome. When I open developer tools the code is still minified.

Anyone have luck with this? To workaround this I'm building my app in debug mode for my production environment so I can debug while others are using it; however, this is slowing the app down upon initial startup.

Comment: Is the source maps file still created but just not shown? Do you get any error message in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, the file is created and no there aren't any error messages in the browser console.

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction project on GitHub or at least add the `pubspec.yaml` and `index.html` to your question?